# rtl in WpF Medinova template

Tags: html, css, wpf, arabic

I am learning web designing in self-study fashion. As a practice, I am using the  WpF Medinova template freely availabe from [here](http://www.free-css.com/free-css-templates/page191/wpf-medinova) . My requirement is to include Arabic content and display it properly. I tried to change the CSS direction to `rtl` and float to `right` in the menu-area in the file style.css line 184.  But it does not work. While the `Home` should appear first, it appears at the end as if it is in English webpage. See this screenshot: [image]

The word with three dots underneath should appear exactly in the firt position.

I would appreciate if you show me how to change the navigation menu direction to appear from right to left.

Comment: just try <li dir="rtl" > to start from right

Comment: @Edison I tried but it did not work, though. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution how you convert LTR to RLT, just follow this link instruction, hope it will help..

https://codex.wordpress.org/Right-to-Left_Language_Support

Comment: Thank you so much for suggesting these magical tools. I used the CSSJanus and I got all the webpages displayed from right to left. Shukran Jazeelan!!